# MVC Render section loading before scripts in Layout

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I seem to be having some issues with the load order of my javascript files. In my _Layout.cshtml I reference JQuery, then I create my script section.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
@RenderSection("Script", false)
```

In my my main view file I reference myScript.js file

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/myScripts.js"></script>

@section Script {
    <script>

        var options = {
            lineGraphData: @Html.Raw(Model.LineGraphJson),
        }

        var viewModel = init(options);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    </script>
}
```

In myScripts.js I have the following click event

```
$('.update-linegraph').on('click', function () {
    UpdateLineGraph();
});
```

However, when the page loads I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

My understanding is quite limited, however, I thought it would have already loaded the jQuery library before the individual view is loaded. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Since your references to "myScript.js" are not in the scripts section they will render in the page wherever they exist inline with your view.  If they are at the top of your view then they will render in the Layout at the point you call RenderBody().  If you load your scripts at the bottom of your Layout then jQuery and all your other scripts will not have been loaded at the point in time your myScripts.js file is loaded and therefore '$' will be undefined.

Try moving your myScripts.js reference inside the scripts section.

```
@section Script {
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/myScripts.js"></script>
    <script>

        var options = {
            lineGraphData: @Html.Raw(Model.LineGraphJson),
        }

        var viewModel = init(options);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    </script>
}
```

Comment: Minor correction: the section is `Scripts`, not `Script`

Comment: The section name is whatever you choose to call it.  In OP's case they have it called "Script" (singular) as defined in the `@RenderSection("Script", false)` line of their first code snippet.

Comment: you are correct. MVC by default has the Scripts section, but the OP is defining their own section.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

it's because I am trying to use jQuery somewhere where I have not properly referenced a jQuery library.

I haven't used jQuery a lot lately so I could be incorrect in thinking this way, but I believe the error is telling you that you haven't referenced a jQuery library in your myScripts.js file.

I would personally try adding your jQuery reference into your myScript.js file as well, like so

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.update-linegraph').on('click', function () {
        UpdateLineGraph();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Alternatively, I've found the the MVC template that's used by Microsoft includes jQuery at the bottom of the Layout page, so the content page tries to reference jQuery before it's been loaded into the page.

Comment: Yes, the more I use MVC the more often I've noticed that when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in which all my scripts within `_Layout.cshtml` were loading at last which causing `$ Jquery not defined` errors. So, what I had to do is:

1. Just move the `<script>...</scripts>` within `<head></head>` tag of `_Layout.cshtml`
2. After that it worked really fine